# Sorting Collection after joinField not working

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, join

I have a collection of products which I filter and show out of stock items only and it works fine. This is what I have:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0));
```

I wanted to sort by Price so I added this:

```
$collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
```

Unfortunately this does not work. and I get a blank page.

If I change the Filter on the Join to show in stock products it works and will show in the correct order

```
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
```

What am I missing?

***Update:***

I removed the filter completely and sorted the collection and it only shows in stock products. It refuses to show out of stock products after sorting.

***Update:***

If I show out of stock products on front end it works:

```
Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options
Display Out of Stock product -> Yes
```

I do not want to show out of stock products on the front end though, only in this collection.

Answer (score 0):

if your `setOrder` not working then you can try below code as well

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('price', 'desc');
```

Also for EAV attribute you can use

```
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('attribute_code', 'ASC'); //or desc as per your requirement
```

Comment: This didn't work it gave the error: THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST